# apr-util configuration problem on AIX 52 and AIX 53 OS

Tags: svn, aix, configure

I am trying to build apr-util subversion dependency library on AIX. Configure errors out saying "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables. See `config.log' for more details." 
I am not sure what am i missing in configuration flags that the config.log ends up saying

```
configure:3064: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3086: /usr/bin/xlc   -L/u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35/lib: conftest.c /u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35/lib: >&5
/usr/bin/xlc: 1501-228 input file /u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35/lib: not found
```

The configure statement is like this:

```
./configure --build=powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0 --host=powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0 
--target=powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0 --prefix=/u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35 
--exec-prefix=/u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35 
--with-apr=/u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35 --with-berkeley-db 
--with-sqlite3=/u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35 
--with-expat=/u/developers/devsys/Subversion/build/AIX35
```

One more thing observed in config.log is before this error there is another error which says

```
configure:3015: /usr/bin/xlc --version >&5
/usr/bin/xlc: 1501-216 command option --version is not recognized - passed to ld
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `configure` script is expected to encounter a lot of errors (because it's testing the system tools), so errors previous to the fatal one are probably not a problem.

Comment: am not sure of what needs to be tweaked for this.